# net/context wrapped on the http.ResponseWriter, good or bad?

Tags: http, go

I needed an [HTTP router](http://www.violetear.org) "violetear" that could support static and dynamic routing, with this I mean, been available to handle request like:

```
/read/book/:uuid/:uuid/
```

> :uuid is something like C6FF0F6F-A274-48F4-B219-6595DCB989A5

Or basic routes like:

```
/read/page/3
```

For the middleware I used [Alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) which helped me to keep things compatible with the http.Handler interface.

So far so good, until the point where I needed to exchange data between the middleware or to access named parameters, like `:uuid` in previous example.

Since the router was used in other projects I wanted to continue keeping compatibility with the [http.Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface, therefore I decided not to pass the `net/context` as an argument between middleware and opted to included in the http.ResponseWriter like specified here: https://github.com/nbari/violetear/blob/master/response_writer.go#L14.

With this approach basically If I need to use the context I have to do something like:

```
func handleUUID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cw := w.(*ResponseWriter)
    // add a key-value pair to the context
    cw.Set("key", "my-value")
    // print current value for :uuid
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Named parameter:, %q", cw.Get(":uuid"))
}
```

Notice the `cw := w.(*ResponseWriter)`.

This is working but wondering if there is any issue by doing the `type` switch or if there are any concerns by doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any problems using your method, nevertheless you can do a profiling to test the speed/memory of your implementation.

Comment: The problem you face with a solution like this is that you hide any of the other implementations of `http.ResponseWriter`, i.e. it's awkward to get an `http.Hijacker` or `http.Flusher` out of the `ResponseWriter`. Within your own code I think it's OK if you know how to handle it, but other code may be expecting to assert one of those other interfaces.

Comment: This article covers the downsides well: https://joeshaw.org/net-context-and-http-handler/